# How to put a banner above the fixed navbar of bootstrap which disappears when scrolling down?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I"m currently working on a project for school to make a ASP.NET MVC website. When i created a new project, bootstrap files were automatically added. So i decided to work with it, but i never did so before.

The first thing i noticed was the fixed navbar at the top of the website. I want a header/banner above it, followed by the navbar. But i didn't manage to do it. I have this code below in the layout view:

```
<div class="movdb-header"></div> <!-- this is the header i want to display above navbar -->

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"> 
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new {area = ""}, new {@class = "navbar-brand"})
        @Html.ActionLink("Inloggen", "Index", "User", new {area = ""}, new {@class = "navbar-brand"})
        @Html.ActionLink("Uitloggen", "Index", "Logout", new {area = ""}, new {@class = "navbar-brand"})
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.movdb-header {
background-color: red;
height: 110px;
width: 100%;
```

}

[image: Layout]

I searched earlier about this problem and people talked about removing the navbar-fixed-top class and then putting your div above it. But i want the navbar to stay fixed but below the personal banner and if scrolled down only the navbar is visible on top. So the banner disappears when scrolling down.

How can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think this will require some custom JavaScript to artificial "scroll" the banner out of view as the user scrolls. With fixed positioning, the nav bar will always be where it's at. By pushing it down far enough for a banner, you'll leave that much gap at the top continually, without modifying the style dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your .movdb-header fixed position and give top: 110px position to your navbar. It is set on top: 0 now.

EDIT:

```
.navbar {
 position: relative;
 }

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100){
            $('.navbar').css('position','fixed');
        }
        else{
            $('.navbar').css('position','relative');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't want my banner to be fixed at the top, i want it to disappear when scrolling down. My navbar must be fixed at the top when scrolling down, but when not scrolled down it must be located under the banner,

Comment: Thank you very much, instead of changing the position to fixed and vice versa i just added the class: navbar-fixed-top when scrolled and removing that class when not scrolled.